# Как реализовать кошелек пользователя на сайте?

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет.

Есть многопользовательский сайт на Laravel. Нужно сделать так, что бы пользователи могли пользоваться платными услугами. С такой задачей ранее не сталкивался, поэтому прошу совета верно ли мое понимание как все должно работать)

1. Подключаем какую ни будь кассу, пусть будет юкасса

Для пополнения счета пользователя

1. Пользователь переводит деньги на наш счет
2. Делаем запись в бд, что такой та пополнил счет на такую то сумму
3. И отображаем эту сумму ему в личном кабинете

Если пользователь хочет что то купить

1. Пользователь что то приобретает у нас
2. Просто списываем со счета личного кабинета потраченную сумму

Все правильно?)

И еще такой вопрос, например пользователь захотел вывести деньги с сайта к себе на карту. Т.е. он подает заявку на вывод 1000 тысячи, на заявки руками нужно обрабатывать или с помощью кассы есть возможность сделать это автоматом?

Comment: Я бы еще табличку завел по операциям пользователей, что бы можно было посмотреть историю движения средств по счету

Answer (score 1):

Все вроде бы логично. Отмечу только то, что нужно фиксировать любые изменения в балансе в логах. И баланс хранить в самой низкой ед. измерения. Для рубля - копейки, доллар - цент и тд.

Выплату можно сделать автоматом([Юкасса](https://yookassa.ru/developers/payouts/overview)). Есть свои нюансы и соответственно комиссия. Если платежей немного, можно и ручками.

Answer (score 1):

На вашем месте я бы сделал полу-автоматический вариант возврата средств. Администратор сайта проверяет аккаунт и подтверждает либо отклоняет а после чего отправляете запрос на ЮКассу и делаете возврат на карту. Если использовать полную автоматизацию то есть шанс что может что то пойти не так, например баг и к счёту добавятся деньги

Comment: Речь идет не о возврате, а о выплате. Не нужно бояться автоматизации и заведомо утверждать, что в вашем коде что-то может пойти не так. Покрываете все тестами, а в любой непонятной ситуации отклоняете платеж и модерируете этот конкретный случай. Думаете банки вручную проверяют каждый платеж? Бизнесу чаще всего нужна автоматизация. Без использования людей.